# App.alert inside dialog box if a certain selection is made

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, dialog

I have a file that I have created to run a code and fill in an engineering drawing. I have created a custom dialog box for it and when the selections in it are made they populate the fields within the document.

A couple of the available selections are Materials, Model, Size and Flange class. The selections I am worried about specifically are Model and Size.

If a user picks model ULJ inside the dialog and goes to pick their size they want and pick either 0.50" or 0.75" I need an app.alert to pop up saying that they can not pick those sizes with that model.

Is this possible to do? I figured it would be inside the validate section of the dialog box but, I am very new to coding and could be wrong. If I am being vague or not giving enough information please let me know and I will try to be more specific. I included a dropbox link to the pdf so you can see what it looks like and the dialog box to help get a better feel for what I am talking about. I am not sure if the link will work because it is my first time using dropbox as well. Thank you to anyone who helps me out in trying to figure this out, I have been trying to for about a week before coming here. Thank you again and I look forward to hearing your responses!

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2v1s3jrqta6bpj6/AAAzd0VDP-XR7theoI1byhnka?dl=0

Here is a very shortened (as much as I think I could) code for my Dialog box.

```
var Section1 =
{initialize: function (dialog) 
 {var listmodl =
  {"ULJ": -1};
   var listsize =
   {
    '0.50"' : -1,
    '0.75"' : -1,
   };
 },
 validate: function(dialog)
 {
  var oRslt = dialog.store();
  var bRtn = true;
  var selectModel = true;
  var selectSize = true;
  for (var e in oRslt["modl"])
   {
    if (oRslt["modl"][e] > 0)
    {selectModel = false;}
   }
  for (var f in oRslt["size"])
   {
    if (oRslt["size"][f] > 0)
    {selectSize = false;}
   }
  if (selectModel == true || selectSize == true)
   {
    bRtn = (4 == app.alert("words",0,0));
   }
  return bRtn;
 },
};
```

I think I have figured out how to achieve this.
This is the code I have created to send an app.alert if the selections made are not allowed:

```
var model = this.getField("partnumber").value
if(model.search("ULJ") >= 0)
 {
  if(model.search(" 08") >= 0 || model.search(" 10") >= 0)
   app.alert("You can not choose that model type with that size of body.\nPlease make a different selection.")
 }
```

Comment: Your intuition is good : you can create custom validation mechanisms for your forms; Many libraries and frameworks exist to help you with that  (e.g. http://parsleyjs.org/). You should also include your current code so that others can suggest helpful changes.

Comment: Okay I will check out the site that you recommended!

Comment: Also when you say to include my current code, do you mean the entire thing? The reason I ask is because it is quite long and has a lot of lines. Thank you for the reply! I did include a dropbox link (if it works if not I will try to add it again) and you could look at the pdf itself and the code. Thank you again.

Comment: Here is the updated dropbox link. The other didn't work when I clicked on it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilw30msvmpca4ur/eductor_dropbox.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The usual practice is to try to summarize your code, focus on the most salient points and insert it right into your post (the text editor allows you to easily format code snippets). Also, whenever possible, it can be a good idea to create a "mock-up" of your problem, using tools such as plunkr (http://plnkr.co/) so that other users can play with your code and see the problem in a "live" environment.

Comment: How did you create the dialog box? using the Dialog object, or an overlay using fields?

Comment: Sorry, I was out of the office on Friday and after lunch on Thursday. I created the combo box using the Dialog object. I have been working on condensing the code to the essentials to past into here. You can view the code and its entirety from the dropbox link a couple comments back. I think it is also worth noting since I did not say this before, this is not a Web-based javascript and it is being used on computers not on a website. I am not sure if that matters or not but, I thought I should say.

Comment: I just included a shortened version of my dialog box code, if you guys need more information on the code or if you need to see more lines let me know and I will include them! Thank you again!

Comment: I think I figured it out finally. I added another set of code in the document that looked at the part number and if it found the combination of the model type, and the sizes it could not be paired with it shows an app.alert that lets the user know that the model they picked cant be paired with the body sizes. It seems to be working like I need it too.